# Why weren't "stray wanderers" heading north a concern for Sauron?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

In Rivendell we know a secret council  between the different races took place regarding the ring. One thing that stands out to me is that in the book it implies that Sauron or at least his servants know that members of different races were heading to Rivendell.

"When you came north, Boromir, you were in the enemy's eyes only one stray wanderer from the south and a matter of small concern to him: his mind was busy with the pursuit of the ring"  (the fellowship of the ring- a journey in the dark)

Now we know that Boromir set off from Gondor much earlier than when the ring actually arrived in Rivendell, so like Gandalf says he may just come across as a wanderer, but shouldn't  the fact that Boromir or any other messenger of the different races heading to Rivendell be alarming for Sauron?! Down to fact all the different races will learn of his ring.

Comment: Why would Sauron know that Boromir or anyone else was going to Rivendell? That's a good thousand miles away from Mordor. And why would he have thought that Rivendell had anything to do with learning of the Ring?

Comment: Even a power-obssessed Ainu can only multitask so much.

Answer (score 4):

Sauron didn't know of the secret council in Rivendell for one simple reason - the meeting in Rivendell wasn't planned in advanced. It wasn't unusual for people to seek out Elrond's advice. In this case it just happened (due to Sauron becoming more active) that representatives from all the good-aligned peoples of Middle Earth came to Rivendell at the same time, looking for answers to their own problems. Gandalf and Elrond simply took advantage of this to call a meeting.

*The Fellowship of the Ring* , Book II, Ch. 2 *The Council of Elrond* :

> [Elrond] ‘That is the purpose for which you are called hither. Called,
>   I say, though I have not called you to me, strangers from distant
>   lands. **You have come and are here met, in this very nick of time, by
>   chance as it may seem.** Yet it is not so. Believe rather that it is so
>   ordered that we, who sit here, and none others, must now find counsel
>   for the peril of the world.

When he set out, Boromir really *was* just "one stray wanderer from the south".

Comment: Didnt Sauron know that the ring ended up in rivendell though?

Comment: @user31546: He certainly knew that the Ring ended up in Rivendell *when it arrived*, or maybe a little after (because the Nazgul could have told him). He almost certainly did not know beforehand that Gandalf and Frodo's plan was to take the Ring to Rivendell, or he would have spent more resources guarding Rivendell and less chasing Frodo down...